# Why do I get CA1811 when I call a private method from a public method in C++/CLI?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, code-analysis, fxcop

I've recently upgraded my project from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010.

By enabling Code Analysis and building on **Release**, I'm getting warning CA1811: Avoid uncalled private code.

I've managed to reduce the code to this:

.h file:

```
public ref class Foo
{
public:
    virtual System::String^ ToString() override;

private:
    static System::String^ Bar();
};
```

.cpp file:

```
String^ Foo::ToString()
{
    return Bar();
}

String^ Foo::Bar()
{
    return "abc";
}
```

The warning I get:

> CA1811 :
>   Microsoft.Performance :
>   'Foo::Bar(void)' appears to have no
>   upstream public or protected
>   callers.

It doesn't matter if `Bar()` is `static` or not.

I've tried to reproduce it in C# but I can't. I can only reproduce it in C++/CLI.

Why do I get this warning?

Is this a Visual Studio 2010 bug?

**UPDATE**

I've decided to open a [bug report on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/560050/getting-ca1811-when-i-call-a-private-method-from-a-public-method-in-c-cli).

Comment: No repro.  You've posted other code analysis warnings that don't repro.  If you've made any config changes then be sure to document them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft guys have reproduced this bug and decided not to fix it.

Suppressing the warning is the workaround.

You are more than welcome to vote for this bug at Microsoft Connect.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/560050/getting-ca1811-when-i-call-a-private-method-from-a-public-method-in-c-cli

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182264.aspx):

> This rule can report false positives if entry points occur that are not currently identified by the rule logic. Also, a compiler may emit noncallable code into an assembly.

In other words, I'm pretty sure Microsoft would say that this isn't a bug, but that the detection techniques of this rules just haven't been very deeply covered yet.

From the same documentation, it also says:

> It is safe to suppress a warning from this rule.

Answer (score 0):

Suggests to me that you wrote a function that is never called.

Comment: No. There's a public ToString() that calls Bar().

Answer (score 0):

If it's only happening in release builds, my guess is that the compiler is dropping the call to `Foo::Bar` and just having `ToString()` directly return `"bar"`.  You can probably verify this by checking the IL.

Comment: Interesting. But even if that the case, it is still a Code Analysis bug, right?

Comment: @brickner: Unlikely.  `Bar` is probably still compiled into the assembly in case it needs to be accessed through reflection.

Comment: The warning tells me to remove the unused method. If I remove it, I get a compilation warning. Doesn't that mean it's a Code Analysis bug?